# Tags Com Tamanhos diferentes

Tags: html, css

**Imagem 1:**
Um Olá, Mundo visualizado no Chrome
[[image: Imagem - 1]
<sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YOfC.png)

**Imagem 2:**
O Mesmo Olá, Mundo Sendo Visualizado no Dispositivo do DevTools do Chrome
[[image: Imagem - 2]
<sup>Clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11WZI.png)

Essa Imagens Mostra oque acontece comigo quando estou desenvolvendo sites

#### Conclusão

A Primeira Imagem o `H1` Está Muito Maior
E Quando eu Vejo Ele Nos Dispositivos do DevTools ele fica bem menor

Como Eu Poderia Corrigi Isso ?
Antes Ele Ficava Normal

Se Alguém pode me Ajuda desde agora muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você abre o DevTools o navegador ajusta a página para a versão de dispositivos moveis.

O que você precisa fazer é utilizar a meta tag viewport dentro da tag `<head>` do seu documento html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a tag abaixo no head do seu html:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

veja mais sobre os artigos do viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag